# Why location 0 in the data segment is not accessible?

Tags: unix

I'm reading Advanced Programming in the UNIX(R) Environment. I'm trying to answer questions at the end of each chapter, but I'm stuck at this one:

*7.4 Some UNIX system implementations purposely arrange that, when a program is executed, location 0 in the data segment is not accessible. Why?*

Comment: Used an HP compiler years ago that had a command line option to allow dereferencing nulls. We didn't know it was enabled by our make config. When we tried to port our code to a different platform it failed horribly due to all of the NPRs...

Comment: I'd figure that by purposely making 0 inaccessible allows for traditional null (0) pointers, and an attempt to dereference one will cause a crash. That can be preferable to inadvertently writing over whatever happens to be located at 0 if you can read/write there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the book has the answer:

> 7.4 This provides a way to terminate the process when it tries to dereference a null pointer, a common C programming error.